# 3ds max CAT Animation layers export

Tags: unity, 3dsmax, fbx

I've made 3 absolute layers [image]

Each layers has it's own animation cycle. Now I would like to export it as FBX and import to unity3d, however, it would import only active layer. 
Is it possible to export it the way, it would be possible to choose later on in unity which animation cycle to play?

Thanks in advance